# ordenar listas con una letra en una determinada posición linux

Tags: linux, lista

mi duda es la siguiente: a la hora de mostrar los archivos de un directorio ¿Cómo puedo hacer que solo se muestren los que contengan una letra (ejemplo j) y que esta este posicionada en tercer lugar ?

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que te estás refiriendo a como llevar a cabo esto en un la shell, en caso de ser así el comando que debes aplicar, en tu caso, es el siguiente:

```sh
ls | grep '^..j'
```

Pudiendo reemplazar "j" por la letra que prefieras, y poniendo **n-1** veces un "." donde **n** es la posición de interés de la letra (n=3 y la letra "j" en este caso).

Lo que vemos después de `grep` se denomina expresión regular, y puedes hacerlas tan complejas como quieras, para elaborar búsquedas más sofisticadas, este enlace puede ayudarte [regex](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-on-linux/).
Espero que te sirva, saludos.

Comment: La pregunta está mal formulada. No dice en que lenguaje necesita la respuesta. Tampoco demuestra esfuerzo alguno.

Comment: @CandidMoe entonces se supone que no debo intentar ayudar en esos casos? Debo criticarle su uso de la plataforma y pedirle más información acerca de lo que necesita? Es así como se procede en estos casos? Lo pregunto enserio porque varias veces me dijeron lo mismo y no entiendo cómo proceder

Comment: La idea es no responder preguntas mal planteadas, incompletas, confusas o que requieran aclaraciones. Suele suceder que después de responder una mala pregunta, el OP te dice que en realidad lo que quería era otra cosa. Trabajo perdido.

Comment: @CandidMoe muchísimas gracias lo voy a tener en cuenta

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda